# How to call parent function from child prop React 15.5.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

Hello I was trying to pass function to child class and call it from the child class but the problem it show the the function is undefined

> Cannot read property 'removeComment' of undefined

here is my codes

parent class:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './notes';

export default class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            comments: [
              'Kingyyy',
              'React',
              'Learning'
            ]
        };
    }
    removeComment() {
      console.log(i);
      var arr = this.state.comments;
      arr.splice(i,1);
      this.setState({comments: arr});
    }
    editComment(newtext, i) {
      console.log(i);
      var arr = this.state.comments;
      arr[i] = newtext;
      this.setState({comments: arr});
    }
    addComment() {
      var text = prompt('enter the new ');
      var arr = this.state.comments;
      arr[arr.length] = text;
      this.setState({comments: arr});
    }
    eachComment(elem, i) {
        return (
            <Navbar key={i} index={i} editComment={(newtext, i) => this.editComment.bind(this)} removeComment={(i) => this.removeComment.bind(this)}>
              {elem}
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <button onClick={this.addComment} className="btn btn-success">add new comment</button>
            <br />
                {
                  this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment)
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

the child class:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
    edit() {
        this.setState({
            edit: !this.state.edit
        })
    }
    save() {
        var value = this.refs.newtext.value;
        this.props.editComment(value,this.props.index);
        this.setState({
            edit: !this.state.edit
        })
    }
    remove() {
      this.props.removeComment(this.props.index);
    }
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.state = {edit: false};
    }
    normal() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.children}</h1>
                <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}>
                    edit
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}>
                    remove
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    editing() {
        return (
            <div>
                <textarea ref="newtext" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
                <br/>
                <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.save.bind(this)}>
                    save
                </button>

            </div>
        );
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.edit) {
            return this.editing();
        } else {
            return this.normal();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is you are losing your react context. Change your constructor for the child class to this

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {edit: false};
    this.normal = this.normal.bind(this)
    this.editing = this.editing .bind(this)
}
```

you call .bind(this) on your remove call... however the `this` you are binding doesn't have the react context with state and props

A few optimizations I would suggest..

define your functions as inline lambdas so you dont have to call .bind(this) on every function every time... aka

```
edit = () => {
    this.setState({
        edit: !this.state.edit
    })
}
save = () => {
    var value = this.refs.newtext.value;
    this.props.editComment(value,this.props.index);
    this.setState({
        edit: !this.state.edit
    })
}
remove = () => {
  this.props.removeComment(this.props.index);
}
normal = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.props.children}</h1>
            <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.edit}>
                edit
            </button>
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.remove}>
                remove
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
editing = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <textarea ref="newtext" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
            <br/>
            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.save}>
                save
            </button>

        </div>
    );
}
```

---

in the parent class change how you pass the functions. Try to always avoid inline lambdas as properties on an element or react class (in the render). It will cause performance issues as the site gets more complex.

```
eachComment = (elem, i) => {
    return (
        <Navbar key={i} index={i} editComment={this.editComment} removeComment={this.removeComment}>
          {elem}
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

if you needed to pass custom variables to a function that were defined inline you can use .bind to pass them through instead of a lambda (bind is a lot more performant than a lambda... aka

```
someList.map( (item, i) => <SomeElement onUserClick={this.handleUserClick.bind(null, item) />);
```

`.bind()`'s first argument is the context `this` you can pass null to not override the context. and then you can pass any other arguments to the function to be arguments extended on the invoked call.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it same problem and the same error
"Cannot read property 'removeComment' of undefined"

Comment: props is undefined. you need to make sure your function has the this context. bind it to all your functions

Comment: it worked after i add this "this.eachComment = this.eachComment.bind(this);" to parent constructor thank you